# Cannot find Incoming Webhook connector in Microsoft Teams

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I had configured an *Incoming Webhook* on one of our Microsoft Teams channels, but noticed it stopped working recently, and also I am no longer able to find the *Incoming Webhook* in the list of connectors:

[image: Missing Incoming Webhook]

What command would I need to have our Administrators run or what configuration would I need to apply to get this to work again?

Comment: Do you see any other connectors listed? If not, could you please ask your admin to [Allow external apps in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant#turn-on-microsoft-teams-for-your-organization)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT - yes there are are total of seven connectors listed: VSTS, Yammer, Bing, Wunderlist, Dynamics 365, MS Forms, TFS. Should my administrator expect to see the webhook as an App as shown on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/enable-features-office-365?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @wajeed-msft notes, this is happening because your administrator turned off access to external applications.

Assuming "Allow sideloading of external apps" is also turned off you'll get the list on the [page you found above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/enable-features-office-365?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#apps). If you scroll through that list, you will see "Incoming webhook" listed.

[image: Incoming webhook in Apps list]

Comment: How fast does this change propagate? Is there any feedback

Comment: @buddyp450 After activating it via: https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/Settings/ServicesAndAddIns I just had to force close Teams (desktop app) and re-open and it was there. It didn't show up until I closed and re-opened it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I didn't remember that I (as a Tenant admin) disabled anything in the portal. "Unfortunatly" the screenshot is from the older portal, in the new Teams Admin check the following:
[image: Org wide settings]

All available connectors were somehow blocked, so I removed everything from the "blocked apps" list:

[image: Blocked Apps]

Then I needed to sign out ("Quit" didn't refresh those settings) and sign in again and now I have access to all connectors.

Answer (score -1):

For webhook connector, you can use the incoming webhook connector in MS teams app sections.
For more information please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-webhooks-connectors/4-incoming-webhooks)

[image: screenshot of Teams Interface]